# Get the latest record related to that id in laravael

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-7

I have two tables as 'customers' and 'transactions'.
all the transactions related to customer gets stored in transactions. Here i want latest record of each customer from transactions table.

Here is my query

```
 $customers = DB::table('customers')            
                ->join('transactions', 'customers.id', '=', 'transactions.custId')
                ->where('customers.status', 'Active')           
                ->select('customers.id', 'customers.custName', 'customers.custMobile', 'customers.custAddress','transactions.custTotalReceived', 'transactions.custTotalBalance')
                ->orderBy('transactions.custTotalBalance','DESC')
                ->paginate(100);
```

expected result shoud be like below

```
name |  mobile | balance  
abc  |   888   |   50   
pqr  |   999   |   150
```

Comment: Is there any transaction date and time? How do you figure the latest record?

Comment: yes there is date time as a "transactions.created_at"

Comment: Just as a sidequestion, why did you decide to use raw DB queries? There is an Eloquent model system with relations that will aid a lot in your application.

Comment: Flame I'm comfortable with this as I'm beginner into Laravel